# SP2007 WebPartPages "Invalid URL Argument" behind URLRewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, sharepoint-2007, reverse-proxy

From **Content Editor WebPart**, editing a page when directly doing it from the SP server is working smoothly.

However, we are getting a pop-up error: `Cannot retrieve properties at this time` when attempting to edit it "outside" the server that is behind reverse proxy.

From Fiddler, we noticed that a hit to `WebPartPages.asmx` is actually throwing 500 with error message: `Invalid URL argument`.

Can anyone share a light on this?

Comment: The last [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5514843-98a3-4ae2-8241-403e12d30183/webpartpagesasmx-500-errors-with-sp2007-behind-f5-ltm) by [MULTISY](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/multisy/?ws=usercard-mini) almost described our problem here, except that ours is not about https.

Comment: Just to share, the problem is not happening in SP version 12.0.0.6514. So far happening in 12.0.0.6421